# Polymorphism Problem C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, reference, polymorphism

I have these classes:

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int val);
private:
    int* m_int;
};

B::B(int val)
{
    m_int = &val;
}
```

I call the code like so, inside 1 function, i know the vars will be destroyed once they are out of scope, but I only need them in this function:

```
{
...
int _int = 0;
B obj(_int);
A *obj2 = &obj;
_int++;
...
}
```

The problem is that _int is changing to 1, but m_int stays the same. I need m_int to reflect what the value in _int is, without the need to update it with code. I thought having a pointer to a memory location would work?

The second problem is that when I hover my mouse over obj2, to see the values of obj, I get the message "children could not be evaluated".

Comment: Does your code compile ?

Comment: There is no way the code you posted can compile. First of all, B's constructor is not declared, second of all, in that constructor, you set `m_int` to the address of `ref`, which appears nowhere else in your code.

Comment: What @iammiling means is that your code should not compile, because `B` does not have a constructor that takes an `int`.

Comment: -1 for posting a code without even first compiling it.

Comment: Was a typo, the code compiles.

Comment: Still... not compiling... what does `ref` refer to?

Comment: crap, another typo, urrrgh. Ive edited

Comment: @PoiXen:  Well done for reducing your problem to a small amount of code.  Next time just try running your code to ensure it still is a good example of the problems you are experiencing with your actual code.

Comment: @PoiXen, I don't think that code should still compile; because `A` is private base of `B`; so you can not assign object of B to A;

Comment: daaaamn. Really sorry. I reduced the code down to make it easy to read. The last 'pblic' typo has been fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `m_int` will stay the same but the *value* pointed to `*m_int` will change, you'll also have to pass the value `val` by reference to the function.

**EDIT:** Saw your edited question, since this is done from the constructor you can do:

```
class B : A
{
public:
    B(int& val) : m_int(val) {}
private:
    int& m_int;
};
```

To have `m_int` reference the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure whether the following is good advice for a novice, but using a reference like this would work:

```
class B : A
{
public:
    explicit B(int& val);
private:
    int* m_int;
};

B::B(int& val)
{
    m_int = &val;
}
```

I'm a bit worried that it is actually a sign of bad design. If it is just for learning purposes, go right ahead, understanding is always important

Comment: +1 for the warning. There are definite life time problems with storing a reference like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change value of _int you should pass it's pointer, they way you're doing now is call by value.

```
B::B(int* val)
{
    m_int = val; // not ref
}
```

and m_int should be of type `int*` not `int`

For second problem, you're storing a value of derived class in a pointer to  base, So when you try to see what's inside obj2 you only see the part of type base, that's why you get message children cannot be evaluated.
Edit--
If you want to see what actually is in obj2, you should cast it to derived type again. And you may not always know that at runtime...

Comment: @AtoMerZ I have seen In online tutorials that if you want to point to a derived class then you do this:
'B obj2;'
'A *obj = &obj2;'

Is this not the right way to do it for this example?

Comment: @PoiXen That's usually done when you have different objects of different classes derived from same base, then you'd store them all in an array of pointers to base class. Or when you have a function parameter in similar circumstances. Otherwise there's **no need** to store derived class in a base class pointer although you **could**.

Comment: @AtoMerZ The problem is. I need to store the derived class in a base pointer and then store in a vector of base pointers. Like so:

'A *obj = &obj2;'
'std::vector<A> vec;'
'vec.push_back(obj);'

Comment: @PoiXen usually in these circumstances it means that you need you objects to behave like base class, then I think you'd not need to see what the object has as derived class. If you do, you should somehow store type information along with every element of you vector, maybe use STL maps, with your objects as keys and type as values.

Comment: @AtoMerZ I dont know if its just me being dumb . . . I do think that using a map would be better, but before that, when 'A *obj = &obj2;' happens -- When I try to check the contents of the obj, all I get is 'children could not be evaluated'. I have a feeling this may be due to my base class? If you look at the original code, all I have changed is A, which now has a default constuctor and deconstructor. Both are empty. In the child class, B, I have used the code from user @Andreas Brinck. seems like it should work and I should be able to see the var in B from A, but I cant. :(

Comment: @PoiXen after a bit of googling I found nothing but it being a probable bug? However in command window, I tried to get contents of obj2 pointer and it worked: showed me empty class (because A has no members), and I tried to cast it to B* then I saw m_int's value. So I guess If you wanna be aware of it's value, you have no choice but to cast it...